# Int function not returning any value

Tags: c++, function, int, return

I made this function to convert a string to an integer (school assignment) and my function is not seeming to work, if it picks up any non-numeric data it should return INT_MAX. It's not returning any data no matter what, and seemingly not returning to main either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int stringToInt(string input){
    int i = 0;

    if(input[i] == '-'){
        i++;
        //First while loop controls valid input
        while(input[i] != '\0'){
            if(input[i] < 49 || input [i] > 47){///Can't figure this out
                return INT_MAX;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    //Now to calculate result
    int result = 0;
    i = 0;
    if (input[i] == '-'){
        i++;
        while (input[i] != '\0'){
            result = (input[i] - 49) + (result * 10);
            i++;
        }
        result = result * (-1);
        return result;

    }
    else{
        while (input[i] != '\0'){
            result = (input[i] - 49) + (result * 10);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}


//////MAIN////////
int main(){
    string number;
    int actualNumber;
    int answer;

    cout << "This is my main function. Enter a string to evaluate" << endl;
    getline(cin, number);

    actualNumber = stringToInt(number);

    cout << actualNumber;
    cout << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but instead of using magic numbers (while `input[i] < 48 || input[i] > 57`), use the standard functions that give you this information: `while (std::is digit(input[i])`. That also insulates you from the uncommon, but not nonexistent possibility that you'll run into a character encoding that doesn't use those particular values.

Comment: This also doesn't address the question, but `input[i] - 48]` is better written as `input[i] - '0'`, which the language definition says will work for all character encodings.

Comment: Take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Answer (score 4):

Your 2nd and 3rd while loops don't increment `i` so you end up looping on the same number forever and never get to `'\0'`.

ie this one

```
    while (input[i] != '\0'){
        result = (input[i] - 48) + (result * 10);
    }
```

`i` never changes.

Comment: Yeah I caught this right after posting and still getting no result after fixing :/
I mean if the function has a string parameter, c++ should know what I mean when doing input[I] - 48 (in regards to 48 being 0 on the ascii table), right?

Comment: Yeah just updated. It's gotta be close. after I enter my string in the terminal, the curser and click enter, the string disappears and the curser doesn't move.

Comment: @IsMrBrightside I recommend using an IDE with a debugger like Visual Studio that way you could break into the debugger and see exactly where it stops and what it is doing. Also make sure you understand how to single step and look at the value of your variables in the debugger.

Comment: @IsMrBrightside your code works for me.  You need to change 49 back to 48 though.